# French characters not showing properly

Tags: mysql, qt

I have a weird issue. I have an embedded system running Linux, QT 4.8 (for touch screen) and MySQL 5.7.8. In my database, I have some entries that contained French accent characters such as "é, à, À, etc"

So, I start mysqld process first, then start my application running QT that will open the database.

This will give me corrupted characters on the screen. For example, the "É" will become "Ã%".

If I restart mysqld, all the French characters will be displayed properly on my screen.

So, it seems my QT application can handle French characters, but I need to restart mysqld to make it happened!

I wanted to start my QT app first and then mysqld after, but I need to get access to the database and because it is not started yet, my app gives an error.

Any clue why?

**UPDATE 20170524**

Here is my database info:

```
mysql> show variables like "collation_database";                            
+--------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name      | Value             |
+--------------------+-------------------+
| collation_database | latin1_swedish_ci |
+--------------------+-------------------+

mysql> show variables like "%character%"; show variables like "%collation%";
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                                           |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                                          |
| character_set_connection | latin1                                          |
| character_set_database   | latin1                                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                                          |
| character_set_results    | latin1                                          |
| character_set_server     | latin1                                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8                                            |
| character_sets_dir       | /mnt/data/part1/usr/local/mysql/share/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+-------------------------------------------------+

+----------------------+-------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value             |
+----------------------+-------------------+
| collation_connection | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_database   | latin1_swedish_ci |
| collation_server     | latin1_swedish_ci |
+----------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Shot in the dark: If your tables have no CHARACTER SET and/or COLLATE defined MySQL is magically using one at startup. On the second start up of the database the local on your system might have changed(?) Try to set a fix character set a collate of the table.

Comment: Lorenz, I edited my question and gave more info about the settings. Does it ring a bell to you? Thanks